How to extract the response body after the "network.responseCompleted Event" using WebDriver Bidi
I'm trying to capture the network response body after the network.responseCompleted Event. I'm not able to find an option in the Selenium Java API to capture the response body.
Network response body for the network.responseCompleted event
